# How to slice numpy.zeros

Tags: python

a = numpy.zeros((1,10))

so it's a 10 x 1 row vector and I want to set the last 3 entries to 1.

I tried a[:-3] but that's the entire last rows assuming it's a matrix and not treating it as last 3 entries for that row.  How would I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a matrix, you can set the last three entries to 1 using the following

```
In [1]: a[0, -3:] = 1
Out[1]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```